# Error Invalid bean definition with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource in addin OAuth2

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have application `Java11` spring boot with CRUD api work find, and I try to add `OpenId` connect plug  for consume, I have error on my bean.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/mypackage/hexa/application/OAuth2SecurityConfig.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=OAuth2SecurityConfig; factoryMethodName=springSecurityFilterChain; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mypackage/hexa/application/OAuth2SecurityConfig.class]] for bean 'springSecurityFilterChain': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=springSecurityFilterChain; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]] bound.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges ->
                        exchanges
                                .pathMatchers("/", "/error").permitAll()
                                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login((Customizer<ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2LoginSpec>) withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String user(Model model,
                       @AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser) {
        model.addAttribute("userName", oidcUser.getName());
        model.addAttribute("audience", oidcUser.getAudience());
        return "user";
    }
}
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauth2SecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration$OAuth2SecurityFilterChainConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'oauth2SecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://idsvr.example.com/oauth/v2/oauth-anonymous"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to override the bean, but that it is not enabled by default.

Set `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`

or if you use *yml* configuration,

```
spring:
   main:
     allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

to enable overriding again.

> **NOTE** : Bean overriding has to be enabled since Spring Boot 2.1,

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes

Comment: now a have thos error

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original error. This is something completely different. You are probably missing the issuer-uri in the property. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673486/unable-to-resolve-the-openid-configuration-with-the-provided-issuer-of-https